# "The resource <URL> was preloaded using link preload" Warning

Tags: html, next.js, preloading

I have a NextJS app and I am adding some images that I need in the `<header>` of the HTML root file.

The way I am adding those images is via the `_document.tsx` file, where I add the links to the `<Head>` as below

```
class MyDocument extends Document {

render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link
            rel="preload"
            as="font"
            type="font/otf"
            href="/font/GothamRndSSm-Light.otf"
            crossOrigin="anonymous"
          />
          <link
            rel="preload"
            as="font"
            type="font/otf"
            href="/font/GothamRndSSm-Book.otf"
            crossOrigin="anonymous"
          />
        ...
```

When I run it on Chrome I get:

```
The resource <URL> was preloaded using link preload but not used within 
a few seconds from the window's load event. 
Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
```

I am "intentionally" preloading. How can I get read of this message?

Comment: Show your html that you use

Comment: Sounds like you don't need to preload, but if you're certain you do, just ignore the message. It only shows in dev mode.